# How to merge two files using for-loop, if-else?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, merge

From the following data below:

```
data01 =

pos     ids      sample1_value   sample2_value
2969    a:b:c    12:13:15        12:13:15
3222    a:b:c    13:13:16        21:33:41
3416    a:b:c    19:13:18        21:33:41
5207    a:b:c    11:33:41        91:33:41
5238    a:b:c    21:13:45        31:27:63
5398    a:b:c    31:27:63        28:63:41
5403    a:b:c    15:7:125        71:33:41
5426    a:b:c    12:13:25        82:25:14
5434    a:b:c    12:17:15        52:33:52
```

say I computed another id (d) value for each sample but not in every lines.

```
data02 = 

pos     ids      sample1_value    sample2_value
2969    d        21               96
3416    d        52               85
5207    d        63               85
5398    d        27               52
5403    d        63               52
5434    d        81               63
```

Problem:

I want to write this value of **d** for each line for each sample.

Is it possible to write the values back using for loop?

**Expected final output:**

```
pos     ids       sample1_value    sample2_value
2969    a:b:c:d   12:13:15:21      12:13:15:.
3222    a:b:c:d   13:13:16:.       21:33:41:.
3416    a:b:c:d   19:13:18:52      21:33:41:.
................................
.......................... in the same way as above
```

**I tried the following code only for sample01:**

```
data01 = open('data01.txt', 'r')
header01 = data01.readline()
data01 = data01.read().rstrip('n').split('\n')

# similar code for data02

data01_new = open('data01_new.txt', 'w')
data01_new.write(header01 + '\n')


for lines in data01:
    values01 = lines.split('\t')
    pos01 = values01[0]
    ids01 = values01[1]
    sample1_val01 = values01[2]

    for lines in data02:
        values02 = lines.split('\t')
        pos02 = values02[0]
        ids02 = values02[1]
        sample1_val02 = values02[2]

        if pos01 == pos02:
            data01_update = open('data01_new.txt', 'a')
            data01_update.write('\t'.join(pos1, (ids01+':'+ids02), sample1_val01+':'+sample1_val02)

        else:
            data01_update = open('data01_new.txt', 'a')
            data01_update.write('\t'.join(pos1, (ids01+':'+ids02), sample1_val01+':'+'.')
```

- I understand that the nested loops waste a lot of time, using the product of the file sizes.
- My if/else logic updates lines with a match, but later overwritten by a mismatch.

Is it possible to fix this using `for-loop and if-else`?

If not, How can I approach this problem using pandas?

Comment: Are the **pos** values guaranteed to be in the same order in both files -- say, increasing integers?

Comment: Can the update file have any new **pos** values?

Comment: Yes, the pos value will be in ascending order. The update file will have all the pos values from data01. To make things clear (data02 has subset of pos values from data01), so all the pos02 will be in pos1 but not all pos1 will be in pos2.

Comment: Great.  Yes, your given code is sub-optimal.  Give me an hour ...

Comment: Yes, I understand it's sub optimal. I have been thinking about it all day, but can't fix it. Also, if you have knowledge in pandas I would like a comparison of the code for my own learning. I hope not to ask too much, but any suggestions is appreciative. Thumbs up !

Comment: Sorry; I'm not a PANDAS user.

Comment: That's fine. Your help with for-loop, if-else should be enough. Thanks much !

Comment: sample2_value should be 12:13:15:. or 12:13:15:96?

Comment: Actually `12:13:15:96`, but since I was trying to work only on sample01 I put `12:13:15:.` not to make things complicated. I would like it for all samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way, first merge the two data on pos and then join the ids, sample1 and sample 2 and finally use only the desired columns

```
data = data1.merge(data2, on = 'pos',how = 'outer').fillna('.')

data['ids'] = data['ids_x'] + ':'+ data['ids_y']
data['sample1_value'] = data['sample1_value_x'].astype(str) + ':'+ 
data['sample1_value_y'].astype(str)
data['sample2_value'] = data['sample2_value_x'].astype(str) + ':'+ 
data['sample2_value_y'].astype(str)
data = data[['pos', 'ids', 'sample1_value', 'sample2_value']]


    pos     ids     sample1_value   sample2_value
0   2969    a:b:c:d 12:13:15:21.0   12:13:15:96.0
1   3222    a:b:c:. 13:13:16:.      21:33:41:.
2   3416    a:b:c:d 19:13:18:52.0   21:33:41:85.0
3   5207    a:b:c:d 11:33:41:63.0   91:33:41:85.0
4   5238    a:b:c:. 21:13:45:.      31:27:63:.
5   5398    a:b:c:d 31:27:63:27.0   28:63:41:52.0
6   5403    a:b:c:d 15:7:125:63.0   71:33:41:52.0
7   5426    a:b:c:. 12:13:25:.      82:25:14:.
8   5434    a:b:c:d 12:17:15:81.0   52:33:52:63.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an amendment of your current logic.

Loop through the update file, one line at a time.
For each new line, advance in the master file to the matching `pos`;
write out non-matching lines on the way.

When you find a match, update the information (which you already know how to do).

```
data01 = open('data01.txt', 'r')
header01 = data01.readline()

# similar code for data02

data01_new = open('data01_new.txt', 'w')
data01_new.write(header01 + '\n')


line01 = data01.readline()
values01 = data01.readline().split(\t)
pos01 = values01[0]

for line02 in data02:
    # Parse next update line.
    values02 = line02.split('\t')
    ids02 = values02[1]
    sample1_val02 = values02[2]
    pos02 = values02[0]

    # Find the next line of master file to update.
    # Extract the pos until it matches update pos.
    while pos01 < pos02:
        # Write the previous line (not matched or updated).
        data01_new.write(line01)

        values01 = data01.readline().split(\t)
        pos01 = values01[0]

    ids01 = values01[1]
    sample1_val01 = values01[2]

    # At this point, you have pos01 == pos02
    # Update the information as needed;
    #   put the result into line01,
    #   so it gets written on the next "while" iteration.
```

Answer (score 1):

If the files are sorted by "pos", you could process a line at the time.

```
def parse_line(line):
    return line.split()

line1 = f1.readline()
line2 = f2.readline()

while line1:

    pos1, id1, v1, w1 = parse_line(line1)
    pos2, id2, v2, w2 = parse_line(line2)

    if pos2 == pos1:
        out_file.write('{:s}\t{:s}:{:s}\t{:s}:{:s}\t{:s}:{:s}\n'.format(
            pos1, id1, id2, v1, v2, w1, w2))
        line2 = f2.readline()
    else:
        out_file.write('{:s}\t{:s}:{:s}\t{:s}:{:s}\t{:s}:{:s}\n'.format(
            pos1, id1, id2, v1, '.', w1, '.'))

    line1 = f1.readline()
```

outputs:

```
2969    a:b:c:d 12:13:15:21 12:13:15:96
3222    a:b:c:d 13:13:16:.  21:33:41:.
3416    a:b:c:d 19:13:18:52 21:33:41:85
5207    a:b:c:d 11:33:41:63 91:33:41:85
5238    a:b:c:d 21:13:45:.  31:27:63:.
5398    a:b:c:d 31:27:63:27 28:63:41:52
5403    a:b:c:d 15:7:125:63 71:33:41:52
5426    a:b:c:d 12:13:25:.  82:25:14:.
5434    a:b:c:d 12:17:15:81 52:33:52:63
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Merge two DFs on pos column
df3 = pd.merge(data01,data02,how='left',on='pos',suffixes=['','_y']).fillna('.')

#transfer data to a numpy array
data = df3.iloc[:,1:].values.astype(np.str).reshape(-1,2,3).transpose(1,0,2)

#concatenate relevant columns with ':' as delimeter.
df3.iloc[:,1:4] =np.core.defchararray.add(np.core.defchararray.add(data[0],':'),data[1])

#take the columns required.
df_final = df3[['pos', 'ids', 'sample1_value', 'sample2_value']]

Out[1372]: 
    pos      ids  sample1_value  sample2_value
0  2969  a:b:c:d  12:13:15:21.0  12:13:15:96.0
1  3222  a:b:c:.     13:13:16:.     21:33:41:.
2  3416  a:b:c:d  19:13:18:52.0  21:33:41:85.0
3  5207  a:b:c:d  11:33:41:63.0  91:33:41:85.0
4  5238  a:b:c:.     21:13:45:.     31:27:63:.
5  5398  a:b:c:d  31:27:63:27.0  28:63:41:52.0
6  5403  a:b:c:d  15:7:125:63.0  71:33:41:52.0
7  5426  a:b:c:.     12:13:25:.     82:25:14:.
8  5434  a:b:c:d  12:17:15:81.0  52:33:52:63.0
```